# React measure, get width of widest of two sibling elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two absolutely positioned sibling elements. I want to use react-measure to set the parent container to the width of the widest absolute element. I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around how to do that.

You can't re-use the measureRef it seems, and if you nested two Measure components the props would collide? Nest them and rename the props in-between? Is there a less ugly way?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out, if you use the HOC `withContentRect` it's a little clearer:

```
const enhance = compose(
    withContentRect('bounds'),
    renameProp('contentRect', 'rect1'),
    renameProp('measureRef', 'ref1'),
    withContentRect('bounds'),
    renameProp('contentRect', 'rect2'),
    renameProp('measureRef', 'ref2'),
);

const Component = enhance(({ rect1, rect2, ref1, ref2 }) => {
    const width = Math.max(rect1.bounds.width || 0, rect2.bounds.width || 0) + 32;
    return (
        <div style={{position: relative, width }}>
            <div ref={ref1} style={{position: absolute}}>Foo</div>
            <div ref={ref2} style={{position: absolute}}>Bar</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```